# Arithmetic addition of pixel intensities in superimposed layers

Tags: gimp

I want, in GIMP, to take two (grayscale) images (same size) and add, arithmetically, the corresponding pixel intensities of their superposition. I have attempted this by using `Paste as...`/`New layer in place` then choosing the Layer Mode `Addition` and then `Layer`/`Merge Down`, but examining the intensities, I'm not sure what it did, but it didn't do what I expected. It sorta tried, but it's not correct (see below). The [documentation](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/layer-mode-group-lighten.html#Addition) says "The pixel values of the upper and lower layers are added to each other. The resulting image is usually lighter. The equation can result in color values greater than 1.0." Am I doing something wrong or do I have incorrect expectations?

*Background*: I need a test image for software that removes fixed-point noise from an image, pixels where the camera has a non-zero intensity in complete darkness, by subtracting intensities from an all "black" reference image from the image being processed. I created a black reference image with noise using the `Filters`/`Noise`/`Hurl` function. Then I added it, as I explained, to a pure gray (`#808080`) 10x10 field.

The image properties are 10x10 size, color space grayscale, precision 8-bit gamma integer, number of pixels 100.

This is the result of the addition (after saving to an ASCII `.pgm` format). Each value on the right should be the value on the left plus 128 (I have omitted zero noise with 128 gray values; those it does correctly):

```
$ paste ~/Downloads/black-noise-10x10.pgm ~/Downloads/gray-noise-10x10.pgm | fgrep -v 128
P2      P2
# Created by GIMP version 2.10.18 PNM plug-in   # Created by GIMP version 2.10.18 PNM plug-in
10 10   10 10
255     255
34      132
78      147
11      129
62      140
63      141
59      139
73      145
29      131
83      149
47      136
```

I also from time to time need to use the `Subtract` or `Difference` mode (to compare images, for example), so this question is relevant to those as well.